# Printing HTML tags into Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to print out an HTML table in Ruby on Rails

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>
<%=     sprintf print_series(@myTable) %>
</p>
```

*The Helper:

```
module WelcomeHelper
    def print_series(graph)     
        res = '<table border="2">'
        graph.each {
            |point|
            res = res + new_row(new_cell(point["date"]) + new_cell(point["value"]))
        }
        res << '</table>'
        return res.html_safe
    end
end
```

Nothing seems to work, I keep getting the HTML tags escaped, such that I can "see" the HTML on my browser, instead of seeing a table.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Moderator... How do I edit my post so it looks normal???

Comment: Indent code lines 4 or more spaces. See my edits.

Comment: thanks alot. sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Highlight the code, and click the `{}` button. It will format the highlighted lines appropriately - I've done this for you.

Comment: @Eran, welcome to stack overflow! Remember to upvote useful answers, including those to others' questions. Check the answer (if any) which best solves your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 automatically escapes html in output.

There are a number of ways to tell it not to do so for selected output.

Here's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3) about the subject

**Added** Drop the sprintf:

```
<%= print_series(@myTable) %>
```

Comment: that's true. I think the problem is that your `sprintf` method outputs a **new** string out of your `print_series.html_safe` output. I don't know why you need `sprintf` but it should work without it. It seems you have inherited some habits from more "rigid" languages, you should definitely learn more about ruby syntax's flexibility - many things are implicit in ruby, not to mention rails. About ruby, i would recommend reading "the well grounded rubyist" book, it is very nice.

Comment: @m_x, correct, a new (unsafe) string is returned by `sprintf` Good recommendation on the book for @Eran. I also suggest the Railscast series, they're excellent.